# Display validation message Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a validate like this :

**TitleRequest.php:**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title_name_report' => 'required|min:2',
        'develop_code' => 'required',
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'title_name_report.required',
        'title_name_report.min',
        'develop_code.required'
    ];
}
```

**Lang/vi/validation.php.**

```
'title_name_report.required'=>"Please enter, :attribute !",
'title_name_report.min'=>"Min length is :attribute",
'develop_code.required'=>"Please enter :attribute !",

'custom' => [
    'attribute-name' => [
        'rule-name' => 'custom-message',
    ],
],

'attributes' => [],
```

**views/title.blade.php**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="title_name_report" name="title_name_report" 
        value="{{old('title_name_report')}}">
    @if($errors->has('title_name_report'))
        <div class="error-text">
            {{$errors->first('title_name_report')}}
        </div>
    @endif
```

I have 2 question :

**1.** How can I display exactly errors message, I have 2 rules but it always display the first rule's message. When I try enter 1 character it still display required message.

**2.** How can I use the langs file so I dont need put message into request files.

Please help me, thank so much !

Answer (score 2):

You can show all validation errors with this :

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Put custom validation messages in `resources/lang/xx/validation.php` file in this format :

```
'custom' => [
    'email' => [
        'required' => 'We need to know your e-mail address!',
    ],
],
```

More Info : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-error-messages

Comment: tks for your support, i followed your guide and it worked  :) !

Comment: Good Luck buddy

Answer (score 1):

1. How can I display exactly errors message, I have 2 rules but it always display the first rule's message. When I try enter 1 character it still display required message.

> Laravel will only validate your input in order. It will not return an
>   error message of the next rules until it didn't pass the first one.

2. How can I use the langs file so I dont need put message into request files.

> You can find to localization details [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization). It is under
>
> /resources/lang/en/validation.php

If you want to change the validation message tru Request file, You should do it like [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#customizing-the-error-messages)

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'title_name_report.required' => "Title is required.",
        'title_name_report.min'  => "Title should not less than 2.",
        'develop_code.required'  => "Code is required.",
    ];
}
```

Comment: Tks, but I tried to enter 1 character, I think it passed the first rule ( required rule ). It did not display the seconde rule ( min rule ) ?

Comment: Can you comment out the  messages() method on your TitleRequest.php? let see what will happen

Comment: i tried this and it worked :D 

'title_name_report.required' => __('validation.corporate_master.title_name_report.required'),

Comment: btw, tks for your support :) !